# How to drop and recreate the temp table in loop in procedure if problem occurs what should we do?

Tags: sql-server

I am tring a lot about the problem that was given in one of my session
that " create one temp table after that create a loop
in that loop drop the temp table which we created and recreate that one"
if we don't create temp table before loop we can get output as 
"Command(s) completed successfully." but if we create that one it is showing error.
please say me the answer to "how to drop and recreate the temp table in loop which already created outside of loop"

```
create proc newp
as
begin
declare @a int 
set @a=5
create table #temp(a int)

while @a >=0
begin

drop table if exists #temp
create table #temp(a int)

set @a = @a-1

end

end
```

Command(s) completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The below way of checking the temp table and drop will work in SQL Server.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp
```

So your stored procedure will be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE newp
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @a INT
    SET @a = 5

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

    CREATE TABLE #temp (a INT)

    WHILE @a >= 0
    BEGIN
        -- IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
        -- CREATE TABLE #temp (a INT)

        INSERT INTO #temp (a) VALUES (@a)

        SET @a = @a - 1

        TRUNCATE TABLE #temp
    END
END
```

Comment: it is coming like "There is already an object named '#temp' in the database."

Comment: @Providemeanswer Do you have any `SELECT ... INTO #temp` statement in your procedure?

Comment: No same as i posted above is my procedure

Comment: @Providemeanswer I prefer to use `CREATE TABLE` once, and `INSERT INTO` the values and `TRUNCATE TABLE` inside the loop. Please check my updated answer

Comment: `#Temp` is an awful name - too much potential for collisions.  I always "salt" my #temp tables with a description of what they'll hold.

Comment: @Providemeanswer If it solves your problem, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043), so others know that the problem has been solved.